# Add class to sidebar parent menu & submenu on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add class `active` to sidebar parent & sub menu on click. I've tried this code, but it won't work. Please check my code and suggest me what and where I missed.

```js
$("#sidebar-menu ul li.with_sub a.active").parents("li:last").children("a:first").addClass("active").trigger("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slim-sidebar" id="sidebar-menu">
  <label class="sidebar-label">Navigation</label>
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li class="sidebar-nav-item with-sub">
      <a href="" class="sidebar-nav-link"><i class="icon ion-ios-home-outline"></i> Dashboard</a>
      <ul class="nav sidebar-nav-sub">
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="menuother.html" class="nav-sub-link">Page 01</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Page 02</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Page 03</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Page 04</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Page 05</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-nav-item with-sub">
      <a href="" class="sidebar-nav-link"><i class="icon ion-ios-home-outline"></i> Menu</a>
      <ul class="nav sidebar-nav-sub">
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 01</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 02</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 03</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 04</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 05</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `li.with_sub` doesn't exist in html

Comment: your jQuery code is very confusing. your question as well. You want to add class on who when click on what ?

Comment: There is no `a.active` element in your HTML? You also seem to be missing an event handler to run your code within.

Comment: @Mohammad li.with_sub, Its there

Comment: No, it is `.with-sub`

Comment: @MihaiT
I want to achive, if click on Page 01 (submenu) Then Dashboard & Page 01 both should addClass (active)
If i click Menu 01 then Menu & Menu 01 both should addClass (active)

Comment: @Mohammad pls let me know how i do this

Comment: In this theme they have created this, i want same thing,but i think i have missed something.
https://coderthemes.com/minton/new-layout/ui-buttons.html

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Check following code, It is working

```js
$("#sidebar-menu ul.nav li.with-sub li a").click(function() {
  $("#sidebar-menu ul.nav li.with-sub li a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $("#sidebar-menu ul.nav li.with-sub a.sidebar-nav-link").removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('a.sidebar-nav-link').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
#sidebar-menu li a.active {
  color: black;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slim-sidebar" id="sidebar-menu">
  <label class="sidebar-label">Navigation</label>
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li class="sidebar-nav-item with-sub">
      <a href="javaScript:void(0)" class="sidebar-nav-link"><i class="icon ion-ios-home-outline"></i> Dashboard</a>
      <ul class="nav sidebar-nav-sub">
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="javaScript:void(0)" class="nav-sub-link">Page 01</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="javaScript:void(0)" class="nav-sub-link">Page 02</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="javaScript:void(0)" class="nav-sub-link">Page 03</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="javaScript:void(0)" class="nav-sub-link">Page 04</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="javaScript:void(0)" class="nav-sub-link">Page 05</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-nav-item with-sub">
      <a href="javaScript:void(0)" class="sidebar-nav-link"><i class="icon ion-ios-home-outline"></i> Menu</a>
      <ul class="nav sidebar-nav-sub">
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="javaScript:void(0)" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 01</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="javaScript:void(0)" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 02</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="javaScript:void(0)" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 03</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="javaScript:void(0)" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 04</a></li>
        <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="javaScript:void(0)" class="nav-sub-link">Menu 05</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working but, i have common sidebar, it should be work after page redirect to other page. It should works on pageload as well

Comment: @Jon lol, then you need server side code there which will store this active class location. It is not possible using html, css, javascript/jquery, You can use session or cookies here but it will be complex and not a good solution

Comment: No, see this link https://coderthemes.com/minton/new-layout/ui-buttons.html they've do this by using jqery only, but im not able to understand how they do this. check this js file from this theme https://coderthemes.com/minton/new-layout/assets/js/jquery.app.js,

Comment: @jon the link you have sent is static html website. In this case you have to put sidebar in every static html page and add active class respectively. If you download this or similar kind of theme you will understand

Comment: yes right, but check they did something like this



// LEFT SIDE MAIN NAVIGATION
      $this.$menuItem.on(event, $this.menuItemClick);

      // NAVIGATION HIGHLIGHT & OPEN PARENT
      $("#sidebar-menu ul li.has_sub a.active").parents("li:last").children("a:first").addClass("active").trigger("click");

Comment: The question you have asked with related tags and your requirement is answered here! Look, The link you have sent is complete theme and it will have many codes that reflects many scenario and functions. Understand you goal - what you want to achieve and possibility of your code and technology you are working with. Learn from scratch and basic things, It will take time but you will understand everything in the end. peace!