# Get no of days in selected month in jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using JqueryUI datepicker. I want to calculate no of days on selected month & display in textbox.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<label for="startDate">Date :</label>
<input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
<input name="noofdays" id="noofdays" />
```

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m5x9ahyb/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onChangeMonthYear` callback is used when a month or year is changed in the datepicker. [For reference](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onChangeMonthYear)

Also, include the Jquery UI after including the Jquery.

```js
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst){
        var year = inst.selectedYear, month = inst.selectedMonth+1;
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 0));
        $("#noofdays").val(new Date(year, month, 0).getDate())
    },
    onChangeMonthYear:function(year, month, date){
        $("#noofdays").val(new Date(year, month,0).getDate());
    }
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label for="startDate">Date :</label>
<input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
<input name="noofdays" id="noofdays" />
```

Comment: @Jon Update the answer

Comment: Can anyone help me on this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53259640/add-class-to-sidebar-parent-menu-submenu-on-click